# Google Maps API V3 character set of title and infoWindow

Tags: maps, character, iso-8859-1

I have a Google map which selects informations from a SQL database. The title an InfoWindow displays this information.

But if the values from the database contain ä, ö, ü, etc. it will be displayed as NULL.

I think I have to change the character set from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 for the map (the PHP site already has this character set).

Is this possible?

Comment: What SQL flavor are you using? Perhaps you could add some information on your database collation or provide some relating code samples.

Comment: I have a similar problem (ASP.net MVC6 with GoogleMaps): loading an address from SQL-Server, generate the title to the marker... and "German Umlaute" like ä, ö, ü are not showed correct. How to format the string with the address correct?

Answer (score -1):

This is the part with the DB selection:

```
function displayLocation(location) {

var image = 'img/pin_s.png';    
var content =   '<img src="' + location.ppic + '" width="90" style="float:left; margin-right:8px; border:black 1px solid">'
                + '<div style="float:left" align="left" class="infoWindow">' + location.cattype + '<br/><br/><strong>'  + location.firstname + ' '  + location.lastname + '</strong>'
                + '<br/>'     + location.city
                + '<br/>'     + location.country
                + '<br/><br/><a href="view_more.php?id=' + location.id + '">Show more ...</a></div>';

if (parseInt(location.lat) != 0) {

    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(location.lat), parseFloat(location.lng));
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map, 
        position: position,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        title: location.firstname + ' '  + location.lastname,
        icon: location.pin
    });
    omarkers.push( marker );
    cmarkers.push( marker );
    umarkers.push( marker );

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        //window.location.href = this.url;
        infowindow.setContent(content);
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
}
```

}

location.firstname e.q. will be displayed as NULL if the Value contains an ä,ö,ü etc.
It´s a MySQL5.5, the values inside are containing this special characters an will be displayed in the "view-more.php" correct.

I can display "Mueller" as title in Google Maps (location.lastname), if i update the db Value to "Müller", the title shows "NULL" as value.

How can i fix this?

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it should be edited into the question.